# Multi-level property?

Tags: python, properties

I need a ***Multi-level @property decorator***.

1. I have a base class `Base`
2. I have a wrapper class `Wrapper`
3. `Wrapper` wraps `Base` and when `Base` is changed, it needs to be reflected to `View`
4. I want to ensure that the change is reflected

***Example of what I need***

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        self.attribute = 0
    @property
    def attribute(self):
        return self._attribute
    @attribute.setter
    def attribute(self, value):
        self._attribute = value

class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self, view: View, base: Base):
        self.base = base
        self.view = view
    @property
    def base.attribute(self):
        return self.base.attribute
    @base.attribute.setter
    def base.attribute(self, value):
        self.base.attribute = value
        self.view.update(value)
```

I know I can simply do the following.

```
    def base_attribute(self, value = None):
        if value:
            self.base.attribute = value
            self.view.update(value)
        return self.base.attribute
```

But since I used `@property` in `Base`, I wanted to keep that style.

Comment: Why not expose `base` with a `@property`?

Comment: @rdas Do you mean I should `@property  def base(self)`? But then when I change `base.attribute` does it call `@base.setter`?

Comment: Yes. It will. Try it.

Comment: @rdas I tried. But to be specific, it called the `getter`. I need to think. Thank you

Comment: when you do `wrapper.base.attr = 10` - it will call getters for `base` & then the setter for `attr` in `base`. If in the getter you just return the `base` it should do what you want

Comment: @rdas It does not fully suffice me. I will be reading `base` from other functions when I do not want the `view` to be updated. `view.update()` in `getter` will be a problem.

Comment: I see. This is not what `@property` is meant for. You should really use the more verbose way. Also a simple assignment updating different class violates the principle of least surprise IMO.